# Unable to delete File

Tags: windows-7, macos, file-management, trash

I'm completely unable to delete a file, which doesn't even show up in Windows, but does in OSX (Mountain Lion) this file was created after uninstalling AppServ (local webserver) Now I need to reinstall AppServ in the same location C:\AppServ, but I can't due to that location being used by that file.

As said, in Windows the file isn't even there (show hidden files checked of course)

In OS X, I've tried rm, rm -f and some file removal script called Trash It! all to no avail.

File in question:

[image]

Error - when I try to do anything with the File, deleting, renaming or anything else.

[image]

What other options do I have to remove this bugger ?

Comment: Did you try a `sudo rm`?  Have you run a disk check to ensure there's no corruption on the disk or in the file-system?

Comment: You describe that you access the file system from both Windows and Mac OS X. Unfortunately you do not describe where is it. Is on a local disk, external disk or network disk? Which file system is it? Microsoft's NTFS, Apple's HFS Plus or something else?

Comment: @pabouk The file is on my Windows partition (Local disk) it's Microsofts NTFS.

Comment: @techie007 `sudo rm AppServ
Password:
rm: AppServ: No such file or directory` Same result

Comment: (1) What happens if you `ls -ld AppServ` (prefixed by `sudo`, if necessary)? (2) Are you talking about a (plain) file called `C:\AppServ`, or a file in the `C:\AppServ` directory (folder). If the latter, can you rename the directory?

Comment: Are you showing system files as well as hidden?  Windows protects system files from deletion as well.

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting, and booting a few times into Windows I suddenly got the "Disk has to be checked for consistency" screen, I did let it run through and the file was gone after that.

So possibly some kind of corruption on the disk / file-system.